# Methodology with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, maven, methodology

I have a data access layer represented by an Eclipse project. I use Hibernate 3 as persistence framework. So, in this project, I have my annotated entities and the resources used by Hibernate (persistence.xml, XXX.cfg.xml).

My question now is more about how QA and production. I have other projects that use this data access layer. Also, my entities may be modified during the project evolution.
When I release one of these projects to QA, and that the data access layer has been modified (entities modifications), the QA database has to been modified accordingly. And that's the same for production.

What are the best practices for this scenario? I use Maven as build system. Do you think the use of hibernate3-maven-plugin is appropriated for this case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend against using `hibernate3-maven-plugin` (with `hbm2ddl.auto`) in production/QA because it might have undesired/unexpected side effects. I think I read somewhere that the Hibernate creators themselves actually recommend against using `hbm2ddl.auto` in production.

It is best to just write your own SQL patches to change the database schema (It will be better optimised as well).

To keep track of the scripts we have directories (in source control) corresponding to a software version (example: 1.14.1) and all SQL patches for changes to run for a specific version (we make sure to keep them re-runnable without side effects) are kept there. When deploying 1.14.1 we run the required scripts for the software release (we also have a script that can automatically run all the required scripts but usually it is done manually).

Comment: The problem is that I've designed the data model from an object view. I mean I first created the entities and their relationships (in the object model), and then I used hbm2ddl to create the schema. So, in my case, I need to create the new SQL schema using hbm2ddl. Which alternative way do you propose?

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear. You can still use hibernate3-maven-plugin to export the SQL schema, just check it manually before running on QA/Production. I would just recommend against using `hbm2ddl.auto` directly on a production database (will update answer).

Comment: Thanks! But my question is larger, I wanted to know more about methodologies that others use every day. I mean how they work, which process they use, ... Also, if you have some resources that explain tips/best-practices about how to work in enterprise.

Comment: Ok I understand, I update answer with what has worked on projects I have done

Comment: So, you have SQL scripts written manually present in the trunk for example. How do you know that the scripts are right? Do you have a systematic procedure to check them? Finally, these scripts will be used by QA to update the test database and by production to update production database. Do you think that the fact it's done manually is dangerous, especially for production database? I just started working after my studies 3 months ago, that explains these beginner questions :)

Comment: The developer will test the script before checking it in and a DBA will check it before running it. If you can trust people to write code you can trust them to write sql scripts. I think it is less dangerous to run a manually checked script than letting a tool update your database. That said I know there are some places that use `hbm2dll.auto` in production and haven't had any problems (yet?). From my own experience and what I gathered from others it doesn't always work as expected (not-null values not changed, triggers disabled etc.).